# Getting HTTP error when trying to install pyaudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

I have a problem when trying to install `pyaudio`. Version of Python that I am using is 3.8.6.

```
Package `pyaudio` found in cache
Downloading package . . .
https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/x2tqcw5k/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pipwin.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipwin\command.py", line 98, in main
    cache.install(package)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 300, in install
    wheel_file = self.download(requirement)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 294, in download
    return self._download(requirement, dest)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 290, in _download
    obj.start()
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pySmartDL\pySmartDL.py", line 267, in start
    urlObj = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=self.timeout, context=self.context)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Do you have pip configured to use some other PyPi repository than pypi.org? What is the output of `pip config list -v`?  Does any of the files listed exist / have any content?

Comment: For variant 'global', will try loading 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\ADMIN\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'site', will try loading 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\pip.ini'

Comment: this is the result

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the [pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) has not been maintained since March 2017. The latest version in pip (0.2.11) does support [only up to Python 3.6](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/0.2.11/#files). To use pyaudio, you'll need to use older, supported Python version.

I don't know why it says *cached resource* `https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/x2tqcw5k/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` is not available. There cannot be such cached resourse since there has never(?) been a build for CPython 3.8.